# Does InOut feedback the out message to a consumer or a producer?

Tags: apache-camel

In this drawing

[image: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.data/flow.png]

From http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html; wouldn't it be more correct - in Camel terms - to state "consumer" instead of "producer" at the left?

I am thinking that the out-reply at the end of the route goes back to the `from("...")` endpoint; i.e. the consumer.

Comment: yes that is correct - I didnt do that drawing ;)

Comment: great - thanks. It was just to make sure that I understood the mechanics correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. The figure was wrong and I was able to edit and update it

The correct figure is online at

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Using+getIn+or+getOut+methods+on+Exchange

It takes a little while for the static html page to be updated.